# Visual Studio 2008 IDE C++: background color of current line

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I would like the line of code where the cursor is currently positioned to have a different background color (like in UltraEdit for those who know it).

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** I'm coding in C++ so ReSharper does not seem to apply (correct me if I'm wrong). I'll give "Slickedit Gadgets" a try (free, unlike "Slickedit" itself).

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freeware add-on that does this and more.

http://www.slickedit.com/products/slickedit-gadgets

I use Resharper to do this.

Comment: On the slickedit site it says it's not free. What are the limitations of the free downloadable version? Is it limited in time?

Comment: @Laurent - umm... 'Free SlickEdit Gadgets' ->Editor Gadgets->Line ruler? Free. as in 'free beer'. The best kind of free. Not sure where the confusion is..

Comment: The confusion was between their main product for which they offer a "Trial" and the "Gadgets"... thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately Visual Studio does not support this feature (although almost every other text editor available does).

Comment: -1 - OP asks if it is possible. it is possible using both commercial and freeware tools.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper can do it, check this [blog post](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/05/16/visual-studio-usability-tip-highlight-current-line.aspx).